# Adding Keyframes to Evaluation-Time Using Python

Tags: python, animation, shape-keys

I am writing a script where I want to automate the animation of Shapekeys. I tried to use the following command:

`obj1.keyframe_insert(data_path = 'eval_time')`, `obj1` is the object containing the Shape Keys.

The command should add a keyframe to the "Evaluation Time" setting for the absoulte Shape-Key:

[image: Insert Keyframe to Evaluation Time]

`'eval_time'` is the data path I have copied via the command "Copy Data Path":
[image: Copy Data Path Command]

However, I get the following message in the system console.

`TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "eval_time" not found`

Using other data-paths like `'scale'` or `'rotation_euler'` works just fine, `'eval_time'` fails, however.

Since this reference I seek to get is nested I have also tried the command using the full ID-path:
`obj1.keyframe_insert(data_path = "bpy.data.shape_keys['Key.002'].eval_time")`, but that didn't work out either.

Can anybody help me out how I can add a keyframe to the "Evaluation Time" attribute using the python API?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**A single property**

You were all round it. Similarly to pythons `getattr(obj, property_name)` the keyframe insert is after the object and a property of that object.

```
>>> obj = C.object
>>> obj.data.shape_keys
bpy.data.shape_keys['Key']

>>> obj.data.shape_keys.eval_time
7.199999809265137

>>> obj.data.shape_keys.keyframe_insert('eval_time')
True

>>>
```

Tip turn on the tooltips and developer extras in *`Edit > Preferences > Interface > Display`*  to assist in finding datapaths.

Answer (score 4):

actually you must see where is each property

the current  [API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Key.html) show that is a main property of all shapekeys

in this case:

```
bpy.context.active_object.data.shape_keys.keyframe_insert(data_path='eval_time', frame=1)
```

this is different for example of "value", that is a specific float in each keyblock

```
bpy.context.active_object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks['Key 1'].keyframe_insert(data_path='value', frame=1)
```